# How can I swipe horizontal left and right with android

Tags: java, android, swipe

I'm new to android and I am making a calendar application to practice. It's almost done but there's 1 thing I can't get to work. I would like to swipe horizontal from left to right to browse months. I've been trying it with this piece of code:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
     {     
         switch(event.getAction())
         {
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
               x1 = event.getX();                         
           break;         
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
               x2 = event.getX();
               float deltaX = x2 - x1;
               if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE)
               {
                    month++; 
                    Log.v("test", "test");
                    theCursor = dbh.getDiaries(month);
                    adapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this, theCursor);
                    this.setListAdapter(adapter);
               }
               else
               {
                    month--; 
                    Log.v("test", "test");
                    theCursor = dbh.getDiaries(month);
                    adapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this, theCursor);
                    this.setListAdapter(adapter);
               }                          
           break;   
         }           
         return super.onTouchEvent(event);       
     }
```

This only swipes from top to bottom and not back, can someone help me fix this code so I can swipe from left to right and back?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the ScrollView

Comment: The XML file that contains the birthday's is coming from a database, is it possible to use scrollview then?

Answer (score 0):

In your xml :

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <--! Your xml -->

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: But how would it know wich month to show? I start by showing the current month, so right now month = 3. Then when I swipe I need it to show month 4.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late reply but it may helps to someone.
Please check updated code below.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
 {     
     switch(event.getAction())
     {
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           x1 = event.getX();                         
       break;         
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
           x2 = event.getX();
           float deltaX = x2 - x1;
           if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE)
           {
             if (deltaX > 0) {
                month++; 
                Log.v("test", "test");
                theCursor = dbh.getDiaries(month);
                adapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this, theCursor);
                this.setListAdapter(adapter);
             } else {
                month--; 
                Log.v("test", "test");
                theCursor = dbh.getDiaries(month);
                adapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this, theCursor);
                this.setListAdapter(adapter);
             }
           }                          
       break;   
     }           
     return super.onTouchEvent(event);       
 }
```